# sveltekit actions for more than function or requst

Tags: node.js, multer, sveltekit, sharp

I need to upload images by sveltekit actions and I used three functions to do so in my back-end node.js and the code.

```
import multer from 'multer';
import sharp from 'sharp';

const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    cb(null, true);
  }
  
  else {
    cb('Please upload only images !', false);
  }
};



const upload = multer({
    storage: multerStorage,
    fileFilter: multerFilter,
  });

  const uploadFiles = upload.array('images', 10);

  exports.uploadImages = (req, res, next) => {
    uploadFiles(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        if (err.code === 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE') {
          return res.send('Too many files to upload !');
        }
      } else if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
  
      next();
    });
  };

  exports.resizeImages = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.files) return next();
  
  req.body.images = [];
    await Promise.all(
      req.files.map(async (files,i) => {
        
   
        const newFilename = `tour-${files.originalname}-${Date.now()}-${i + 1}.jpeg`;
  
        await sharp(files.buffer) 
          .resize(640, 320)
          .toFormat('jpeg')
          .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
          .toFile(`upload/${newFilename}`);
         
        req.body.images.push(newFilename);
    // console.log(req.body.images);
  
   
    
  
  
   
  
  
      })
    );
  
    next();
  };
  
 
  
  exports.getResultImages = async (req, res,next) => {
    if (req.body.images.length <= 0) {
      
      return res.send(`You must select at least 1 image !`);
      
  
    }
   
    const images = req.body.images.map((image) => '' + image + '');
   // res.status(200).json(req.body.images)
   req.body.images = images;
    res.locals.images = images;
    console.log();
    next();

    
  
    
  };
```

so, how could I do it with sveltekit actions, to handle req for more than req, is it the right way or I just have to make the req from the back-end, and is there any alternative for multer and sharp I mean to deal with sveltekit

Comment: should I use (Custom event listener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this's what I found to upload multiple files with svetekit it might help anyone.

**+Page.server.js**

```
import  sharp from 'sharp';


export const actions = {
    add: async ({ request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData()
    let file = data.getAll('file')
    console.log(file);
    const names = file.map(user => user.name);
    console.log(names);
    if (!file) return next();
  

    await Promise.all(
      file.map(async (file,i) => {
  
     let filename   = `tour-${"file.originalname"}-${Date.now()}-${i + 1}.jpeg`;

        if (file) {
            

          
          let ab = await file.arrayBuffer()
          console.log(Array.from(ab));
  

          await sharp(ab)
          .resize(500, 500)
          .toFormat('jpeg')
          .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
          .toFile(`static/img2/${filename}`);
          return { success: true }     
        }
    })
    
    );}
  };
```

**+page.svelte**

```
<script>

    export let form
    export let data

</script>
<!-- svelte-ignore missing-declaration -->
<form 
    action="?/add"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    
  >
<input
      multiple
      type="file"
      name="file"
      id="file"
      accept="image/*" class="file-input file-input-bordered file-input-error w-full max-w-xs"
    />
    <button>upload</button>
</form>
```